# Duplicate bash prompts

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, arch-linux

I'm having an interesting issue with XFCE Terminal/Gnome Terminal (not reproducible in XTerm), where executing `bash` or logging in using `login` or `su` will open a new Bash instance inside a Bash instance as shown:

`_randall@manbearpig:/home/randall[root@manbearpig randall]#`

Ctrl+D and exit both exit back to the original bash instance. How do I make these terminal emulators behave like Xterm, which opens the new user account or bash instance over the original one?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  typing `bash`, `login` or `su` are SUPPOSED to start a new shell.  What is it that you expect to happen?  Because, I cannot see where your system is doing anything wrong.  if you want to open another TERMINAL program, then type `gnome-terminal` or whatever the program name is.  Bash is a shell, where you type commands, gnome-terminal, xterm, konsole (and lots more) are just terminal emulators which show the output of a shell (bash/sh/dash/ksh/csh/zsh...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the problem. typing `bash`, `login` or `su` are **SUPPOSED** to start a new shell.

What is it that you expect to happen?

I cannot see where your system is doing anything wrong.

if you want to open another TERMINAL program, then type `gnome-terminal` or whatever the program name is.

*Bash* is a *shell*, where you type commands, *gnome-terminal*, *xterm*, *konsole* (and lots more) are just *terminal emulators* which show the **output** of a shell (bash/sh/dash/ksh/csh/zsh...)

Comment: I understand that those commands start new shells; sorry for causing confusion. The issue I'm having is purely cosmetic; typing `su` into an XTerm window and logging in won't cause duplication of prompt (i.e. user@hostname[user2@hostname]); rather, you'll end up with just the second prompt until you log out of it or exit the window.

Comment: That is likely something in your PS1 environment variable being displayed, and something in your shell startup scripts which does that.  If you're using bash, check the files in `/etc/bash*`, `$HOME/.bash*`.   Just need to figure out which file/script is being cute and making the huge prompt.

Comment: It was the export TERM=screen line in my bashrc. This also fixed some spacing in my IRC client and IM client. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

if

```
_randall@manbearpig:/home/randall[root@manbearpig randall]#
```

is not the prompt string you expect, then check PS1 environment var which contains the prompt string format. Search "PROMPTING" in bash manual to read more about PS1.

Comment: My PS1 variable (the default) is the one I prefer; my issue is a cosmetic one: using a terminal emulator like XTerm will display `[randall@manbearpig randall]` upon executing the `bash` command in the home dir, but Gnome-Terminal and XFCE Terminal give `_randall@manbearpig:/home/randall[randall@manbearpig randall]#`, which seems unnecessarily long and ugly from a usability standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use something like:

```
exec bash # or exec login or exec su
```

But be careful, as this replaces the parent process, the whole window/tab will likely die and there is no guarantee the new shell will "save" it. You'll have to try it yourself, I can only guarantee it works in Konsole.